# What are reference assemblies in .Net? How are they created? Can we create one ourselves?

Tags: reference, assemblies, clr

I dont understand the concept of reference assemblies such as Silverlight for WP7 profile, Metro Style Apps Profile, etc. What do they mean when they say these assemblies are not real assemblies but meta data assemblies which refer actual assemblies.

I understand this is a very generic question so any information that you share will be hellpful.